# undefined variable on CI controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some issue on `$PYParentID` for the following code. I'll always get and *undefined variable error* that showes up when I execute my post action. Am I missing something?

Error message

> Undefined variable: PYParentID loc: C:\xampp\htdocs\kawaguchi\apps\modules\Account\controllers\D‌​ownPaymentAp.php line: 301

```
$this->db->insert(T_AccountPayableHeader, $PYHeader);

//print_r($PYParentID);die;

$PYParentID = $this->db->insert_id();
$detailPayment = $detail->first_row("array");
$payableID = $vendor->first_row("array");   

$PYDetail = array(

    T_AccountPayableDetail_RecordStatus => "",
    T_AccountPayableDetail_RecordUpdatedOn => date('Y-m-d g:i:s',now()),
    T_AccountPayableDetail_RecordUpdatedBy => $this->ezrbac->getCurrentUserID(),
    T_AccountPayableDetail_RecordUpdatedAt => $this->input->ip_address(),
    T_AccountPayableDetail_PRI => $PYParentID,
    T_AccountPayableDetail_DocTypeID => $headerData[T_MasterDataDownPayment_DocName],
    T_AccountPayableDetail_DocNo => $headerData[T_MasterDataDownPayment_DocNo],
    T_AccountPayableDetail_DocDate => $headerData[T_MasterDataDownPayment_DocDate],
    T_AccountPayableDetail_DueDate => "",
    T_AccountPayableDetail_DaysOverdue => "",
    T_AccountPayableDetail_InvoiceAmount => $headerData[T_MasterDataDownPayment_Amount],
    T_AccountPayableDetail_AmountPaid => $headerData[T_MasterDataDownPayment_TotalAmount],
    T_AccountPayableDetail_AmountOutstanding => "",
    T_AccountPayableDetail_Bank => $headerData[T_MasterDataDownPayment_BankAccountNo],
    T_AccountPayableDetail_SchedulePayment => "",
    T_AccountPayableDetail_PONo => $detailPayment[T_MasterDataDownPaymentDetail_PoNo],

);
```

Comment: try putting your print_r AFTER $PYParentID is set.

Comment: thats not the real problem, i have tried that.. but what is showing up is error code:100

Comment: Are you sure that it's this actual code that throws that error? Add the actual and full error message + show us what line it's throwing it at.

Comment: yes, when i execute the action the error that appear is Undefined Variable $PYParentID

Comment: msg: Undefined variable: PYParentID
loc: C:\xampp\htdocs\kawaguchi\apps\modules\Account\controllers\DownPaymentAp.php
line: 301

Comment: ...and what line is 301?

Comment: T_AccountPayableDetail_PRI => $PYParentID,

Comment: With the above code, that shouldn't be possible. The above is the actual code, copy/pasted, nothing removed/added or rewritten? It's not in different methods or anything like that?

Comment: that's what i confused about

Comment: oke wait, i'll give you the extended code maybe you can help wait a minute

Comment: where can i copy paste the syntax ? its too long

Comment: @andreibrahim only copy and paste entire method from which you got error . No need to copy entire controller code. Only method is sufficient

Comment: yes, but the relatable error is a litle bit far with the code

Comment: if the only method is needed, i've already said it above